# How do I enable Sharepoint 2013 rich text editor ribbon Table Styles?

Tags: styles, sharepoint-2013, ribbon, rich-text-editor

In my SharePoint page → rich text editor ribbon, the table styles button is disabled and greyed out. After inserting the table, I am not able to apply any table styles. I don't know how to enable it. I tried the below option, but it didn't work.

```
#Ribbon\.Table\.Design\.Style\.TableStyles{
    display: block
}
```

When I try to remove the tablestyle completely from the ribbon using the below code, it works fine. But when I try to enable it using `display:block`, the TableStyle option is appearing in the ribbon, but it is greyed out.

```
#Ribbon\.Table\.Design\.Style\.TableStyles{
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the page layout, in PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField Tag, the property useinlinestyle was set to True. i changed that to FALSE after which i was able to enable table styles.

but still i dont know how or from where the inline styles (aria disabled or ms-cui disabled) were coming.